# Add Header to CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to programmatically add a header to an already existing CSV file using Python. The problem is that I do not want to overwrite the first row of the file, I would like to push all data downwards by one row and add the header on the first row without overwriting anything. Can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible to add data at the beginning of a file, you can only replace content or add data at the end of a file.

The solution would be to write a new file with your header and all the content of your original file.

Comment: is it possible to merge 2 csv files, one with the headers and the other with the data?